# Regex for float matching strings like "12." also?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried with this regex to match floating values:

```
(^\d{0,11}$)|^\d{0,11}([.]\d{0,6})?$
```

However, I don't want to allow strings like `12.`, i.e. a number with a dot at the end.

Please me give me a suggestion.

Comment: I tested the regex at regexstorm.net.. It matches '12.'

Comment: You probably wanted to write it as `^\d{0,11}(?:\.\d{1,6})?$`. If you use `\d{0,6}`, the pattern may match an empty string. BTW, to test JS regex  use regex101.com, e.g., regexstorm only supports .NET regex and uses CRLF line endings.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d{0,11}(?:\.\d{1,6})?$
```

If you use `\d{0,6}`, the pattern may match an empty string. Note that it is not recommended to test JS regex with RegexStorm.net as it only supports .NET regex and uses CRLF line endings.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{0,11}` - zero to eleven digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,6})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\.`  - a dot
  - `\d{1,6}` - 1 to 6 digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Np1OX4/2).

Answer (score 0):

How about you restrict the count of the decimal part.. like this

```
^\d{0,11}(?:\.\d{1,6})?$
```